# .NET Core application does not start

Tags: c#, .net-core

I create an application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Preview (version 16.3.0 Preview 2.0). After I published it using CLI, application does not start on consumer's machine without an error.
When tried to start using CLI consumer gets this error:
[image]

But .NET Core 3.0.0 preview runtime is installed
[image]

When I publish as full package (with all libraries placed in the app's folder) app is working OK.

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: looks like you have to rebuild.

Comment: Tried several times with no action

Comment: try a clean first.

Comment: deleted whole release folders, no result

Comment: Publish with --self-contained attribute

Comment: Also I think that the machine where you publish and the client machine have different os or different os architecture you may need to specify runtime os https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

Comment: @hovjan in case I publish with --self-contained, it puts runtime to app's folder. I want to have an application and push user to install .net core 3.0 preview runtime package. I don't want to have runtime libs inside app's folder

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean? I have only one dotnet.exe inside `C:\Program Files\dotnet`

Comment: @BohdanBessonov is this a console app ? If yes just remove referenced  Microsoft.WindwosDesktop.App lib

Comment: @hovjan it's WPF app with window-based UI

Comment: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true` Is a way to get single exe, but I want to use system's runtime instead

Comment: Then you have to install the runtime (3 preview) on all machines that need to run this!

Comment: @matt_lethargic as shown on the second screenshot, runtime 3.0.0-preview8 is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue in dotnet/wpf repository about it:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/656

Probably current workarounds are:

- Deploy app as self-contained.
- Install SDK on client machine.

Comment: Thanks you, followed this question!